# Validation Failed on Entity Response when Using Posts API

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using the POST API to retrieve a specific post by URN, but I keep getting a 400 response with the message

> Validations failed on the UGC entity. Please see errorDetails for more information.

The response body doesn't have an `errorDetails` property, so there isn't any further details.

Here's my request:

```
{
    "method": "GET",
    "include_raw_body": false,
    "parse_response": "true",
    "url": {
        "full_url": "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts/{{post urn}}"
    },
    "body": {
        "none": null
    },
    "query_parameters": [
        {
            "key": "oauth2_access_token",
            "value": "AQ... <**--removed--**>"
        }
    ],
    "headers": [
        {
            "key": "authorization",
            "value": "Bearer  AQ... <**--removed--**>"
        },
        {
            "key": "LinkedIn-Version",
            "value": "202306"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the response:

```
{
    "message": "Validations failed on the UGC entity. Please see errorDetails for more information.",
    "status": 400
}
```

I am following the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2024-01&tabs=http#sample-request

What is causing this issue? I've tried a different URN and that request came through correctly. The issue appears limited to this specific UGC entity.